# how to use prefix name without xmlns

Tags: xml

I followed the code from W3School:XML Namespaces.

And I get an error:

> XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
>   Location: http://localhost/XML/dasar/tes.xml
>   Line Number 4, Column 1:

How to fix it without xmlns ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <h:table>
        <h:tr>
            <h:td>Apples</h:td>
            <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
        </h:tr>
    </h:table>
    <f:table>
       <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
       <f:width>80</f:width>
       <f:length>120</f:length>
    </f:table> 
</root>
```

Comment: "How do I use namespaces without `xmlns`?" How do I eat without food? How do I smell without a nose? The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: **If you have** those prefixes `f:` and `h:`, then you **must define** the corresponding XML namespaces in your XML document. Period. If you do not want to do that, then **you cannot use** these prefixes. Period again.

Answer (score 1):

You either do not add any namespace or you need to define your namespaces.

Do not add any namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <name>African Coffee Table</name>
  <width>80</width>
  <length>120</length>
</table> 

</root>
```

Define your namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table> 

</root>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Exactly. W3Schools literally tells you that you must define a namespace for your prefixes and gives an example of how. And they're not wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock ...this time.